# Wild Card Search line notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I want to search for all lines that have **CREATE**, **TABLE** and **HIST** or variation of **Hist***(Hist, History, Histry, Histroy, etc). How to do that? Thank you

```
CREATE <Any text here> TABLE <Any text here> HIST <Any text here>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should do the job:

```
\bCREATE\b.*\bTABLE\b.*\bHIST.*
```

Where:

- `.*` matches 0 or more any character but newline
- `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Don't forget to check *Regular expression* and  *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

Comment: yup, got it working, slight edit       \bCREATE\b.*\bTABLE\b.*HIST\b.*     Thank you :)